# I can't perform a REST request with Sencha

Tags: rest, extjs

I want to perform a rest request with sencha ext js. Threfore I created a model and a store with a proxy. Then I invoked the load function of the store. The problem is that after the invocation the store is still empty. I know this because I debugged it. This is the code:

```
var myModel = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {
    fields: [
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'age' }
    ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: myModel,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/blablabla',
    }
});

myStore.load();
```

The url 'http://localhost:8080/blablabla' is correct because when I type it in the browser I get the json list of users with the "name" and "age" fields. So the server works.

Here is an example of json that I should get:

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "john",
  "age": 40
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "jack",
  "age": 30
} ]
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of you'r JSON return please ?

Comment: The documentation states that the proxy will have to set on the model and not on the store, maybe is something like that ? (https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.6.0/modern/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.html)

Comment: But there are also some examples of proxies inside a store: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html

Comment: I think i might have something to do with CORS. Because the actual response of the request is 'Invalid CORS request'

Comment: Oh yeah sorry didn't read this.
It's you'r server wich response CORS error or navigator ?

Answer (score 0):

My Sencha code was correct. The problem was CORS not enabled. So I resolved by adding `@CrossOrigin` above my server method.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping
public List<Thing> getThings() {
    ...
    return myListOfThings;
}
```

`@CrossOrigin` did the trick.

Comment: That's not appropriate way of developing. Requests to your own server shouldn't refer to domain/port, but only to path. Don't use sencha's app watch server, but instead serve the sencha's workspace from withint your own web application.